# Create a new column for each occurence of character string in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Suppose I have the following .txt file:

```
Alabama[edit]
fooAL
barAL
Arizona[edit]
fooAz
barAz
bazAz
Alaska[edit]
fooAk
...
```

How can I convert this into a pandas data frame of the form

```
| St. Name | Region |
|----------+--------|
| Alabama  | fooAL  |
| Alabama  | barAL  |
| Arizona  | fooAz  |
| Arizona  | barAz  |
| Arizona  | bazAz  |
| Alaska   | fooAk  |
| ...      | ...    |
```

So what I thought was use the [edit] character string that appear after each state name as the `sep= '\[edit\]'` as an argument in the `read_csv` in `pandas` . But it doesn't give me what I want.

But I still think I can use some sort of regular expression here to do what I want without writing for loops or anything like that. Can you please help?

Comment: And that does look a lot like [Week 4 of Introduction to Data Science in Python](https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-data-analysis) on coursera :)

Comment: Yes it is. They encourage you to ask questions on stackoverflow. So I did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest not relying on pandas directly here, but do to the parsing by opening the file and dealing with it line by line to construct a list of dict, and use that to create a dataframe:

```
with open('yourfile.txt','r') as f:
    content = f.read().splitlines() 

state = None
l_dict = []
for line in content:
    if '[edit]' in line:
        state = line.split('[')[0]
    else:
        l_dict.append({'St. Name':state, 'Region':line})

df = pd.DataFrame(l_dict)
df.set_index('St. Name', inplace=True)
```

---

If you really want to do in pandas, I guess you could do it this way by handling States and Regions separately, and using a [forward fill](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) of NaNs (`DataFrame.ffill` is the same as `fillna(method='ffill')` (or `pad`)

```
df = pd.DataFrame('yourfile.txt', columns=['txt'])
# Create a column that'll serve as a filter IsState
df['IsState'] = df['txt'].str.contains('\[edit\]')

# Split and get first item of split
df.loc[df.IsState, 'St. Name'] = df.loc[df.IsState, 'txt'].str.split('[').str.get(0)

# the `~`means not
df.loc[~df.IsState, 'Region'] = df.loc[~df.IsState, 'txt']

# Forward fill the NaNs
df['St. Name'] = df['St. Name'].ffill()

# Select what you truly want and set index
df = df.loc[~df.IsState, ['St. Name', 'Region']]
df.set_index('St. Name', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# header is None and names=['St. Name']
s = pd.read_csv('yourfile.txt', header=None, squeeze=True, names=['St. Name'])

# grab [edit] lines
st = s.str.extract('(.*)\[edit\]').ffill()
# groupby
g = s.groupby(st)
# use tail(-1) to get all but first row
df = g.apply(pd.Series.tail, n=-1)
# reset_index to get what we want
df.reset_index('St. Name', name='Region')
```

[image]

---

***same thing in one line***

```
s = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), header=None, squeeze=True, names=['St. Name'])

s.groupby(s.str.extract('(.*)\[edit\]').ffill()) \
    .apply(pd.Series.tail, n=-1) \
    .reset_index('St. Name', name='Region')
```

Comment: Me likey! Very elegant.